# Как заменить только 1 повторяющийся элемент строки через регулярные выражения?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:
/states/kvartiry/osn_komnati-is-1/apply/&field=CREATED_DATE&method=ASC&PAGEN_1=2

Необходимо заменить первый & на ?

Как можно обратиться к нему и заменить?

Comment: надежнее поменять код который вставил &

Comment: Не подходит такое "решение"

Answer (score 0):

Ниже предствлено решение, мы получаем 3 части (`до &`, `&`, `после &`) потом вместо второй чати вставляем `?`:

```
$url = "/states/kvartiry/osn_komnati-is-1/apply/&field=CREATED_DATE&method=ASC&PAGEN_1=2";
$res = preg_replace('/([^&]*)(&)(.*)/','$1?$3', $url);
```